# Transversality of an involution

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am supposed to show that given an involution of a smooth manifold X without boundary, i.e. a diffeomorphism $\phi:X\to X$ such that $\phi$ is it's own inverse, then the fixed point set of $\phi$ given by
$$\{x\in X\;|\;\phi(x) = x\}$$
is a submanifold of X.

My approach was showing that the map $f:X\to X\times X,\; x\mapsto (x,\phi(x))$ is transverse to the diagonal $\Delta:=\{(x,x)\in X\times X\;|\; x\in X\}$ in $X\times X$. If this is true then we know that $f^{-1}(\Delta)$ is a submanifold and corresponds precisely to the fixed point set.
I know that when $\phi$ is the identity my approach does not work, but can it work for non-trivial involutions, and if so, is there a nice way to compute the tangent map of $f$?